# TypeError: require(...).registerUser is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am trying to import registerUser function inside router.post, in the same file in which i have exported its function (registerUser) so that it can be used outside this module also but it says

TypeError: require(...).registerUser is not a function

please have a look -

```
**user.js // express route for 'api/user/signup/ --------**



const router = require('express').Router();
const userModel = require('../models/user');

exports.registerUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('in registeruser')
}

router.post("/signup", (req, res, next) => {
    require('./user').registerUser(req, res, next);
    console.log('in signup')
    next();
})


module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't require the same file you're already in.

Instead just create the function, and then later on export it. Your code would then look like this.

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const userModel = require('../models/user');

async function registerUser(req, res, next) {
    console.log('in registeruser')
}

router.post("/signup", (req, res, next) => {
    registerUser(req, res, next);
    console.log('in signup')
    next();
})

exports.registerUser = registerUser;

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Thanks @sleeppyy, it worked one question - why it was not working if i was exporting it by directly declaring as a export function ? but it was working if i declare it first, then i export it by calling the declared function variable?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are trying to reimport it, just declare it as a variable and use it directly, you can still export it

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const userModel = require('../models/user');

const registerUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('in registeruser')
  next();
}

// since registerUser is also middleware, you can pass it as a param to post
router.post("/signup", registerUser, (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('in signup')
  next();
});

exports.registerUser = registerUser;
```

Comment: Thanks @sleeppyy, it worked one question - why it was not working if i was exporting it by directly declaring as a export function ? but it was working if i declare it first, then i export it by calling the declared function variable?

Comment: @homevilla it doesn't work because you override the default export further down (i.e. `module.exports = router`). You would need change this to export the `router` as a named export as well. However, there is no benefit here of reimporting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the registerUser in the same file, you don't need to export it.

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const userModel = require('../models/user');

registerUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('in registeruser')
}

router.post("/signup", (req, res, next) => {
    registerUser(req, res, next);
    console.log('in signup')
    next();
})


module.exports = router;
```

If you want to use the registerUser in other modules, simply export it by modifying your exports statement

```js
module.exports = {router, registerUser}
```

Comment: Thanks @
shubhendu madhukar, it worked one question - why it was not working if i was exporting it by directly declaring as a export function ? but it was working if i declare it first, then i export it by calling the declared function variable?